# What do I do with all my beans?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I bought a bunch of magic beans from the guy sitting outside of Zora's Domain when you are a child. I could only find two locations to plant them (the one right near where he is sitting, and the one in the Kokiri Forest). I still have a few (I spent quite a bit of money on this, thinking they would be useful), but I don't know where else to put them.

Where else is there ground for planting beans?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a total of 10 locations to plant the magic beans as child Link, the majority of which will result in obtaining a piece of Heart as adult Link.

These should be all of the locations:

1. Zora's River: near the salesman that sells you the magic beans
2. Kokiri Forest: near the Shop
3. Lost Woods: near the stage where you entertain the Deku Scrubs
4. Lost Woods: near the bridge that exits to Hyrule Field
5. Graveyard: near where the gravekeeper's tomb will be when you're adult Link
6. Death Mountain: near the cavern entrance
7. Death Mountain Crater: near the Triforce platform
8. Lake Hylia: near the laboratory
9. Gerudo Valley: at the bottom near a cow
10. Desert: near the entrance to the Spirit Temple